# tmux: How to get the expression (for config file) of the pressed key?

Tags: emacs, tmux

Environment is Konsole + xterm-256color + tmux.

I like `bind-key` *[Prefix] Alt+Backspace* to `next-window`, so I wrote the following line in `~/.tmux.conf`

```
bind-key M-BSpace next-window
```

It worked well. But now, it suddenly stop working after maybe the system upgrade or something whatever. I need to know how to get the correct **expression** for `bind-key`. (I mean, `M-BSpace` may be an invalid expression)

Is there any way to get the exact expression of the pressed key in tmux? For example, just like Emacs's `C-h k`, which can display the exact expression of a pressed key-binding.

This method is very useful because I can know whether Emacs accepted a correct key-binding, or the key-binding cannot interpreted/interpreted as something else by Konsole, xterm-256color, or tmux. (e.g. `C-2` will be interpreted as `C-@`, `C-i` as `TAB`)

Comment: The man page lists the special key names, like `BSpace`, and the `M-` or `C-` prefix syntax. You can use `xbindkeys -k` to get what key you are pressing, but it uses standard X11 names like `BackSpace`, so you need to convert.

Comment: Nan, `xbindkeys -k` cannot solve my problem.... Updated my question

Comment: I dont know if this can help, but you can get extensive debug of what tmux is doing by running it with `tmux -v`, then every char you type produces lines in a file `tmux-server-*.log` such as: `keys are 1 (\b), ... writing key 0x8 (C-h) to %0`